# How to Find Resource Id for Google Drive File

Tags: android, google-drive-api, resource-id

I was looking through the Android Google Drive API and understood its overall workings but I was wondering what exactly the resource id of a file or folder is. Can this only be found for a query or is can this be found simply through looking at the document? Furthermore, is there any way to access a public Google Drive document through the API?

Answer (score 3):

By doing [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) you get back a list of all the files and directories with in a directory.

Google returns to you a [file Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) for each file or directory you will find the id or the resource id for that file.  Check out the `q` option for `files: list` you can search on file name with that to find the resource id for the file you want.   I am actually not sure if you can see that by looking at the document on the website.

Side note: folders are also consider to be files in Google Drive API they just have a mime type of

```
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
```

Comment: okay thank you, do you know how this could be done with public documents?